# Electrical conductivity of graphite

Tags: physical-chemistry, conductivity, carbon-allotropes, electrical-properties

On [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resistivity_and_conductivity#Resistivity_of_various_materials), the electrical conductivity of various materials are given in the third column ($\sigma \text{ (S/m) at 20}^\circ \text{C}$).  I am interested in the entry for **Carbon (graphite)**:

- $2$ to $3 \times 10^5 \text{ S/m} \perp \text{basal plane}$
- $3.3 \times 10^2 \text{ S/m} \parallel \text{basal plane}$

Why is conductivity *lower* parallel to the plane than in the direction perpendicular to the plane?

I am surprised by the relative magnitudes of these $\sigma$ values because I thought that one of the amazing things about graphene -- an atomic layer of graphite -- was that its conductivity *in* the plane (i.e., parallel to the basal plane) is very high.  I would expect a similar trend parallel to the basal plane in graphite.

Do you have any suggestions for reading that I can do to understand this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Good catch - you are absolutely correct. This is a mistake in the Wikipedia page, as a quick check with the reference listed there confirms. The values are the wrong way around.

Changing it now...

**Edited to add:** this of course raises the question of *why* it should be this way around. A somewhat hand-wavy answer is that, just like in benzene, the $p_z$ orbitals overlap within each graphene sheet so that the electron contributed by each carbon is delocalised in this plane (the other three are bound up in the three $\sigma$ bonds). So in a sense this is conjugation, but over a whole 2D plane rather than around a ring or along a single chain of atoms. On the other hand, the graphene sheets are rather further apart from one another than the covalently bonded atoms within a sheet (as you might expect since the sheets are only weakly bound through van der Waals interactions), and so the overlap is greatly reduced and conduction is much more difficult.

A more complete answer would rely on a study of graphite's electronic band structure, which is an active research area and beyond the scope of this response!

Comment: Just as a follow-up, *why* is the electrical conductivity higher in the parallel direction?

Comment: You assumed that already in Your question, why?